# Can't display my uploaded images in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I need you. I'm trying to display my images stocked in DB postgres. But I can't cause when I'm trying, I have just an icon of unloaded image. I don't know Where is the problem. Here's my controller.

```
    #[Route('/publication', name: 'publication')]
    public function temp(Environment $twig)
    {
        $drawRepository= $this->entityManager->getRepository(Draw::class);
        $draws = $drawRepository->findAll();
        return new Response($twig->render('draw/show.html.twig', [
            'draws'=>$draws

        ]));
    }

}
```

and the part of my template

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}


    {% for draw  in draws %}
            <img src={{ asset("./public/uploads/draws/" ~ draw.post) }}/>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

thanks in advance for your answers

Initially, I packed all features in one Method but finally I split  the recuperation and the submission of my images in two Methods as you can see. Unfortunately It didn't help me.

Comment: What does `draw.post` dump? Does `/public/uploads/draws/` exist and have images inside?

Comment: It dump the image's name. Yes /public/uploads/draws/ exist ans have images inside.

Comment: Usually, you don't use `./` with `assets()`, but I don't think this is the problem. However, I would add double quotes around the `src` value of your `img`. What does the resulting html looks like?

Comment: @MajorSigma, as Julien has mentioned, check in your browser inspector and see what the html is actually rendering out as..

Comment: In the browser inspector, the html is rendering

`<img src= "asset(public/uploads/draws/ " ~ draw.post)> `
for each images uploaded.

Comment: Try with quotes like `<img src="{{...}}"`.

Comment: it don't work i have the same icons

Comment: Well you have your problem, that src should be showing a url. That is what you have to debug, from the info so far, I'm unsure. Is the asset component installed?